# Cordova plugin media audio speed

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, media

I'm using the Cordova Plugin Media plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media), with Ionic 1.x

How do I set the speed of an audio? For example, the iOS Podcast application, where you can set the audio speed in 1x, 1 1 / 2x, 2x ...

I need to increase the speed of the audio that is playing. Is it possible to do this with this plugin? If yes, how? If not, what is the best alternative?

Best regards

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I see a `media.setRate`, but it's only supported on ios.  I'm having a similar problem where it just looks like playback speed isn't supported at all on Android